# ASP MVC 5 Update-Database Throwing Entity Validation Error After Customizing Identity Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, seeding

I have updated my Identity Models as follows because I needed to extend the IdentityUserRole class so that I could add additional properties to it:

```
 public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin { }
 public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim { }

 public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole
 {
    public ApplicationUserRole()
    : base()
    { }

    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
 }  

 public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<string, ApplicationUserRole>
 {
    public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
    public ApplicationRole(string name) : this()
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public bool HasPermission(string permission)
    {
        return Roles.Any(r => r.Role.Permissions
                  .Any(p => p.Name == permission));
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, string> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

To accommodate the above change I created a new application userstore as follows:

```
public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, 
    ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

And updated identity.config file so that the usermanager uses the new userstore:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, string> 
{ 
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, string> store) 
        : base(store) 
    { 
    } 

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(
        IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)  
    { 
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(
            new ApplicationUserStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>())); 
        ...
    }
}
```

In my seed method I have the following:

```
 var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(context));

 var user = new ApplicationUser();

 user.UserName = "joe.blogs@domain.com";
 user.Email = "joe.blogs@domain.com";
 user.FirstName = "Joe";
 user.LastName = "Blogs";

 string userPWD = "Abcde_1";

 userManager.Create(user, userPWD);
```

When I run the update-database command I'm getting the following error:

```
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
```

Writing the error to a text file it shows:

```
Entity of type "ApplicationUser" in state "Added" has the following validation errors: 
- Property: "Id", Error: "The Id field is required."
```

Why do I need to provide an Id field - isn't it suppose to be autogenerated as I'm still using a string for the primary key? My users table is no different to what it was before:

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.User",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    FirstName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 255),
                    LastName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 255),
                    Email = c.String(maxLength: 256),
                    EmailConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    PasswordHash = c.String(),
                    SecurityStamp = c.String(),
                    PhoneNumber = c.String(),
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    LockoutEndDateUtc = c.DateTime(),
                    LockoutEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    AccessFailedCount = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    UserName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.UserName, unique: true, name: "UserNameIndex");
```

Comment: I've had to add the following to the ApplicationUser class to fix:  `public ApplicationUser()  { this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); }`. So if you want extended any of these identity models but wish to retain the default string primary key, it looks like you have to go and re implement it's regeneration in each class that your are extending?

Answer (score 0):

I've had to add the following to the ApplicationUser class to fix: public ApplicationUser() { this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); }. So if you want extended any of these identity models but wish to retain the default string primary key, it looks like you have to go and re implement it's regeneration in each class that your are extending